# Problem copying and pasting non-contiguous Excel columns using ActiveX

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

I want to open and process a number of Excel files using Matlab. The task is to copy and paste an area to a new sheet in a new Excel workbook. The area is defined by a contiguous selection of rows (e.g. rows 1 to 3) but a possibly non-contiguous selection of columns (e.g. columns 1 and 3). A requirement is that the copying-and-pasting operation should preserve comments.

The requirement that comments are to be preserved led me to the use of ActiveX as opposed to xlsread and xlswrite. I am able to open, select and paste a contiguous selection to a new file and save that file but I fail to make the selection non-contiguous.

The following lines are key:

```
DataRange ='A1:C3'; % Select contiguous selection.
Sheet1.Range(DataRange).Copy; % Select the columns to copy.
Sheet2.Range('A1').PasteSpecial(13); % Paste, including comments.
```

All is well so far and the code behaves as intended.

I then try to modify the code to cope with non-contiguous columns as follows:

```
 DataRange = 'A1:A3, C1:C3'; % Only select first and third columns.
```

Matlab returns with an opaque error message (Object returned error code 0x800A03EC) rather than reaching the intended outcome where the contents of rows 1 to 3 and columns A and C are selected and copied.

Unfortunately my VBA skills are non-existent and I do not know how to proceed. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction using this simple example.